# Angular ng-repeat element. Reset toggle-switch on view-change

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-lists

I have list produced by a ng-repeat which iterates an array of objects. 
For each element created i have a ng-click that toggles a showDetails-body.
Like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat-start="order in orderList " 
     ng-click="order.showDetails = !order.showDetails"
```

How do i toggle that specific element to be false when i change the state of the whole window (i.e change view)? The problem is that the list-elements "body" with details show when i change view in the app. i need to reset that specific element. is it possible?

Comment: I guess you can just call `$scope.orderList[yourIndex].showDetails = false`

Comment: I don't know the index. It might be many list-elements that are expanded. And they sort of stick to the page when i change the content.

Comment: Then just go through the whole list and set each of their `showDetails` to `false`

Comment: Try ng-click="orderList[$index] .showDetails = !orderList[$index] .showDetails"

Comment: @BenyaminCoskuner . I thought about that. but how do i do that when i have set the property in the view? I will have to force a refresh on the ng-repeat dont i?

Comment: Tried. didn't work Vivz

Comment: No you don't actually. Angularjs will pick it up on detection change cycle. Try it, it should work.

Comment: not able to find a solution. Is it possible to clear the values in the scope created by ng-repeat?

Comment: Why can't you simply iterate over all orders, like was suggested by  @BunyaminCoskuner? Try something like `angular.forEach($scope.orderList, function(order){ order.showDetails = false; });` in your controller.

Comment: I ended up creating a method in my controller using the forEach function. It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $scope.collapseListItem = function(){
        $scope.orderList.forEach(function(element) {
            element.showDetails=false;
        });
    }
```

this fixed my problem. I call this function in my view with a ng-click() when changing my view.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ng-repeat** in place of **ng-repeat-start**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="order in orderList " 
  ng-click="order.showDetails = !order.showDetails">{{order.name}}
  {{order.showDetails}}</li>
</body>
```

Let the coltroller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.orderList = [{"name":"John","showDetails":false},
           {"name":"Doe","showDetails":false}
      ];
});
```

Working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Yc5zU7VRP41qWQfP0IsC?p=preview